# How to find object in list and compare it in pygame?

Tags: python, function, loops, class, pygame

How can I tell which objects are being displayed on the screen or being shoot at in pygame? I would, for example, want to be able to give different health to different objects so that it takes more shoots to kill one type of object (or asteroid in this case)

Enemy class

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, y, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.y = y
        self.x = random.randrange(30, 500 - 64 * 2)
        self.index = random.choice(number)
        self.hitboxes = [(self.x + 68, self.y + 68, self.width - 10, self.height - 14),
                         (self.x + 38, self.y + 47, self.width + 20, self.height - 5),
                         (self.x + 18, self.y + 12, self.width + 32, self.height + 30),
                         (self.x + 20, self.y + 32, self.width + 16, self.height + 5),
                         (self.x + 4, self.y + 7, self.width - 24, self.height - 31)]
        self.hitbox = self.hitboxes[self.index]

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(asteroids[self.index], (self.x, self.y))
```

Variables. Defining the variables associated with the enemy (asteroids)

```
asteroids = [pygame.image.load('rock0.png'), pygame.image.load('rock1.png'), pygame.image.load('rock2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('rock3.png'), pygame.image.load('rock4.png')]

number = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

bullets = []
asteroids_on_screen = []
rock = Enemy(-140, 64, 64)
```

Main loop.

```
while run:
    [...]
        elif event.type == asteroid_delay:
            x = random.randrange(screen_width - 64 * 2)
            index = random.choice(number)
            asteroids_on_screen.append(Enemy(rock.y, rock.width, rock.height))

    for a in asteroids_on_screen:
        if -141 < a.y < 650:
            a.y += a.vel
            a.hitbox = (a.hitbox[0], a.hitbox[1] + a.vel, a.hitbox[2], a.hitbox[3])
        else:
            asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))

    for a in asteroids_on_screen:
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.x + bullet.width < a.hitbox[0] + a.hitbox[2] and bullet.x - bullet.width > a.hitbox[0]:
                if bullet.y - bullet.height < a.hitbox[1] + a.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.height > a.hitbox[1]:
                    if milliseconds > 700:
                        milliseconds -= 10
                        pygame.time.set_timer(asteroid_delay, milliseconds)
                    bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                    if a.hitbox == a.hitboxes[0]:
                        print('Working')  # statement here to identify object on screen 
                    asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))

        if man.hitbox[0] < a.hitbox[0] + a.hitbox[2] < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] or man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2] > a.hitbox[0] > man.hitbox[0]:
            if man.hitbox[1] <= a.hitbox[1] + a.hitbox[3]:
                man.hit()
                asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))

    for bullet in bullets:
        if 0 < bullet.y < 600:
            bullet.y -= bullet.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))

    [...]

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would, for example, want to be able to give different health to different objects so that it takes more shoots to kill one type of object (or asteroid in this case)

According to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57860627/how-to-create-a-global-variable-from-a-local-and-store-its-previous-value) `a` is an instance of the class `Enemy`.

Add an attribute health to the class:

```py
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, y, width, height, health):
        self.health = health;
        # [...]
```

Note, the health can be a random number (e.g. `random.randint(1, 5)`).

When the `Enemy` object `a` is hit, then decrement the health. If the health is `<= 0`, then the enemy is killed:

```py
for a in asteroids_on_screen:
    for bullet in bullets:
        if bullet.x + bullet.width < a.hitbox[0] + a.hitbox[2] and bullet.x - bullet.width > a.hitbox[0]:
            if bullet.y - bullet.height < a.hitbox[1] + a.hitbox[3] and bullet.y + bullet.height > a.hitbox[1]:
                if milliseconds > 700:
                    milliseconds -= 10
                    pygame.time.set_timer(asteroid_delay, milliseconds)
                bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
                a.health -= 1
                if a.health <= 0:
                    asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))
```

---

It is even possible to add a strength to the bullets:

```py
class Projectile:
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color, strength):
        self.strength = strength 
        # [...]
```

and to decrement the health by the strength:

```py
bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullet))
a.health -= bullet.strength
if a.health <= 0:
    asteroids_on_screen.pop(asteroids_on_screen.index(a))
```

Comment: the thing is that the ```if a.hitbox == a.hitboxes[0]:``` statement doesn't work. It has no effect. All the asteroids still have the same health

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen Sorry, this was not correct. You don't need that at all. I've changed the answer. All you need is `a`, because `a` is the reference to the `Enemy` object and the object can hold any data you won't. Store everything what belongs to the object in the object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will probably do a power-up that strengthens the bullet. However, this gives all the objects the same health, right? How can I do different healths for different asteroids?

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen Of course. I think the type of the asteroid is the `self.index`, isn't it. Create an array with the health values (e.g. `a_health = [7, 3, 9 ...]`) and then `self.health = a_health[self.index]`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!